# AVX512 static rounding mode has no effect

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, avx512

I'm new to AVX512 and I'm trying to modify a function written in inline assembly using AVX2 to utilize AVX512 specific features.

When I try to specify a static rounding mode in a suitable instruction, it has no effect on the result. No exception is caused and the program just runs without crashing but with wrong results.

I've tried using this on a scalar instruction such as:

`vmulss xmm3, xmm1, xmm0, {rz-sae}`

and a packed instruction like:

`vfnmadd231ps zmm10, zmm11, zmm7, {ru-sae}`

without any success. I've read through the manuals of Intel on AVX512 and I also checked the code bytes generated by the compiler, but I didn't find anything.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 with the Intel C++ Compiler and an i7-11850H CPU.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What result do you get?  You're not expecting it to round to an integer or something, do you?  Rounding isn't needed if the result can be exactly represented as a `float`, e.g. 1.25 from 2.5 * 0.5, the result is exact in that case, so the IE (inexact) status flag in MXCSR wouldn't be set even without SAE.  Rounding affects the lowest bit of the mantissa.  Without a [mcve], we can't tell what the problem was in your expectations, or in how you built the program or whatever.

Comment: Works on my PC, or at least, it had an effect for some values that I put in. For example 0.13 * 0.13 (in single precision) rounded either up to 0.016899999 or down to 0.016899997 depending on the mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for answering so fast. I used vroundss before to truncate. I expected to have the same result with static rounding as with vroundss. So if only the lowest bit of the mantissa is affected by static rounding. That means vmulss with {rz-sae} will not round an intermediate result like 0.1945 to 0.

Comment: @harold Okay. I think that means I had wrong expectations. I thought I could replace vroundss by static rounding.

Comment: Correct.  It has the same effect as changing the rounding mode in MXCSR to something other than nearest (with even as a tie-break).  Normal FP math operations only round to the nearest representable float (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_decimal_values_(between_1_and_16777216)), and this just overrides the rounding *direction*, not how much rounding happens.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the explaination. I understand now. Couldn't vroundss to truncate a FP number be replaced by a logical instruction to zero out the corresponding bits?

Comment: @Loran: No, `0.9` has a different exponent field than `1.0` or `0.0` (have a look on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html for those numbers, and e.g. 4.0, 4.75, 4.99, 4.9999, 5.0, 5.25, 7.5, 8.0).  Even if truncating toward zero for numbers with magnitude above 1.0 (so I think the exponent field could stay the same) you'd need multiple bitwise operations to find the number of mantissa bits to clear based on the exponent field.  Plus that could mess up NaN payloads, and could turn a NaN into +-Infinity if you zeroed all the mantissa bits.